# Saving external command file descriptor output to golang

Tags: go, file-descriptor

I have an executable that does some task and save the result in a csv file.
I want to control the output from golang by using os.cmd

```
cmd := exec.Command("generate.exe")
cmd.Run()
```

I can control only stdout of generate.exe but not the file it generates

Is there a way to save the csv file in a golang struct, variable rather than saving it to a file?

Comment: Go is free from magic, so a clear "No!" here. But: Once the file is generated, just read it in (e.g. via package os) and parse the CSV (e.g. via package encoding/csv).

Comment: I was thinking about creating a named pipe before running the go code which will be used  to redirect the output to the named pipe like generate.exe -o namedpipe.

Golang will continuously check the named pipe for data and save it to buffer.

is this possible?

Comment: That is possible. But it is complicated and hard to debug. Note that SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the generated file from stdout, but you can read the file generated by the script generate.exe with package 'encoding/csv'. Read this documentation [encoding/csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#pkg-overview)